# Knockout foreach data binding for JSON does not returning any values

Tags: json, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

HI I'm developing simple web using web api with Knockout. I wanted to display a list of data from the Json structure.

```
    function OrganisationViewModel() {
         var self = this;
         self.Organisations = ko.observableArray();

         var baseUri = '@ViewBag.ApiUrl';
         $.getJSON(baseUri, self.Organisations);


     }
     $(document).ready(function () {
         ko.applyBindings(new OrganisationViewModel());

     })
```

above code is to get JSON and set it to the Observable array.

```
<div>
    <ul id="update-Org" data-bind="foreach: Organisations">
        <li>
            <div>
                <span data-bind:"text: $data.Name"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span data-bind:"value: $data.PhoneNumber"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

above is HTML for printing out JSON data.
output only returns nothing but 4 dots. which means it knows I have 4 items in the array.
I'm pretty sure it is not about the empty JSON data because I get following JSON data.

```
0: {$id:1, Contacts:[{$id:2, Organisation:{$ref:1}, Id:1, ContactName:bg1, OrganisationId:1},…],…}
$id: "1"
Contacts: [{$id:2, Organisation:{$ref:1}, Id:1, ContactName:bg1, OrganisationId:1},…]
0: {$id:2, Organisation:{$ref:1}, Id:1, ContactName:bg1, OrganisationId:1}
1: {$id:3, Organisation:{$ref:1}, Id:2, ContactName:bg2, OrganisationId:1}
2: {$id:4, Organisation:{$ref:1}, Id:3, ContactName:bg3, OrganisationId:1}
Devices: []
Id: 1
Licenses: []
Name: "Aug1"
PhoneNumber: "021"
1: {$id:5, Contacts:[], Licenses:[], Devices:[], Id:2, Name:Aug2, PhoneNumber:02111}
$id: "5"
Contacts: []
Devices: []
Id: 2
Licenses: []
Name: "Aug2"
PhoneNumber: "02111"
2: {$id:6, Contacts:[], Licenses:[], Devices:[], Id:3, Name:Aug3, PhoneNumber:0211333}
$id: "6"
Contacts: []
Devices: []
Id: 3
Licenses: []
Name: "Aug3"
PhoneNumber: "0211333"
.....
```

Comment: It might be me, but I can't get your json data. Could you format it? Also one of the things I'd change is the way you retrieve your json data. You are alredy getting all your data in the response, is it necessary getting your data in a new ajax request? You could format it on the server side (json.net might be useful) and assign it directly to your js variable.

Comment: I just followed the tutorials from the ms website. Only difference is that I'm using edmx(model first) data rather than code first.

Comment: Please check your browser's JavaScript console! Are there any errors?

Comment: retrun is my most common way how misspelling return too :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  replacing your getJSON with this:

```
$.getJSON(baseUri, function( data ) {
    self.Organisations(data);
});
```

I suspect that your current getJSON function overwrites your observableArray with a normal array.